# Dynamic function not seeing the extended object's method

Tags: c#

I have a function that handles two different objects that I don't really have access to because they are in two different libraries. The two objects I am using have the same method, GetElementValue() that always returns a string because I extended one of the objects to do so. Here is a sample of the dynamic function, **which is in the same namespace as the extension** but in two different class files (NOTE: This is a custom C# library used in a REST API):

```
private void SetContentDynamic(dynamic xmlElement)
{
    //Defaults
    this.Title = xmlElement.GetElementValue("Title"); //This is where the error occurs
    //lots more code below
}
```

Here is the extended method for the XElement object:

```
public static class XElementExtension
{
    public static string GetElementValue(this System.Xml.Linq.XElement xelement, string xname)
    {
        if (xelement != null) {
            System.Xml.Linq.XElement temp = xelement.Descendants(xname).FirstOrDefault();
            if(temp != null)
                return temp.Value;
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

Now I receive the following .NET Internal Server error 500 suggesting that at runtime it is not recognizing that I have the extension method for the object.

```
'System.Xml.Linq.XElement' does not contain a definition for 'GetElementValue'

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
```

Is there an ordering problem when this class file is compiled down into a DLL that is causing this, or is there a way for me to make sure that the extended method can be found? I have tested the extended method on a non dynamic function that explicitly takes in System.Xml.Linq.XElement and it runs fine, but because I have two objects that get passed through this method I would much rather prefer to have 1 dynamic method instead of duplicating the code in 2 explicit methods.

Comment: Why is `xmlElement` dynamic in the first place?  is there a possibility that it will be anything other than an `XElement`?

Comment: Yes @D Stanley, It can be a secondary object that inherently has the GetElementValue() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extension methods are bound at compile time - the compiler converts the method call into a call to the actual static method.  `dynamic` defers all binding to run-time, where there's no mechanism to search for appropriate extension methods.

You could simulate that binding and just call the static method directly:

```
private void SetContentDynamic(dynamic xmlElement)
{
    //Defaults
    this.Title = XElementExtension.GetElementValue(xmlElement,"Title"); 
    //lots more code below
}
```

But that will fail at runtime if `xmlElement` is not an `XElement`.  I would just declare the parameter as an `XElement` unless you have a reason for making it `dynamic`

Comment: Thank you, this sounds like a perfect explanation of why I am running into this problem.

Comment: I have added a second extended method for that secondary object that basically calls it's GetElementValue() function so that I can call the XElementExtension.GetElementValue() function for both objects and keep 1 dynamic function.

Comment: @WarGravy I would add that as another "answer" so that it is distinct from what I have provided.  If you want to accept your answer rather than mine that's perfectly fine.